# Guzzle open localhost:8099 when request to another resource: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost:8099

Tags: php, laravel, http, curl, guzzle

I use laravel (8.78.1) with GuzzleHttp client. I make calls to some domain. There are no usage of http://localhost:8099 in my code, but I see the error message in my logs on production when the code calls . I've set up the project on Ubuntu, using the docker, php:8.1-fpm, with certbot/certbot:v1.22.0. It is running as a docker container. I tried to install it without docker, but it works in the same way. Despite this error message, the actual request are executing successfully. The code finishes without exceptions.

There is no such problem on my local machine.

> local.ERROR: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7:
> Failed to connect to localhost port 8099: Connection refused (see
> https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for
> http://localhost:8099 in
> /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:210

Code:

```
    public function list(): array
    {

        // ...

        $url = $this->getRequestUrl("customer/list");
        $client = $this->getClient();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
        $responseArray = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        // ...

    }

    protected function getRequestUrl(string $endpoint, string $params = ""): string
    {
        return "{$this->getBaseUrl()}$endpoint";
    }

    protected function getClient(): Client
    {
        return new Client([
            'base_uri' => $this->getBaseUrl(),
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            ]
        ]);
    }

    protected function getBaseUrl(): string
    {
        return "https://example.com/api/";
    }
```

Stack trace:

```
[2022-02-15 19:41:58] local.ERROR: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8099: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://localhost:8099 in /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:210
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(158): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(110): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#2 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#3 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#5 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(64): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#6 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(31): GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#7 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RedirectMiddleware.php(71): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#8 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(63): GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#9 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php(75): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#10 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(331): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#11 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(168): GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#12 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(187): GuzzleHttp\Client->requestAsync('POST', Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri), Array)
#13 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/jkocik/laravel-profiler/src/Processors/BroadcastingProcessor.php(57): GuzzleHttp\Client->request('POST', 'http://localhos...', Array)
#14 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/jkocik/laravel-profiler/src/Processors/BroadcastingProcessor.php(42): JKocik\Laravel\Profiler\Processors\BroadcastingProcessor->broadcast(Object(JKocik\Laravel\Profiler\LaravelDataTracker), 'http://localhos...')
#15 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/jkocik/laravel-profiler/src/LaravelDataProcessor.php(58): JKocik\Laravel\Profiler\Processors\BroadcastingProcessor->process(Object(JKocik\Laravel\Profiler\LaravelDataTracker))
#16 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php(242): JKocik\Laravel\Profiler\LaravelDataProcessor->JKocik\Laravel\Profiler\{closure}('JKocik\\Laravel\\...', 0)
#17 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/jkocik/laravel-profiler/src/LaravelDataProcessor.php(62): Illuminate\Support\Collection->each(Object(Closure))
#18 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/jkocik/laravel-profiler/src/LaravelProfiler.php(96): JKocik\Laravel\Profiler\LaravelDataProcessor->process(Object(JKocik\Laravel\Profiler\LaravelDataTracker))
#19 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): JKocik\Laravel\Profiler\LaravelProfiler->JKocik\Laravel\Profiler\{closure}()
#20 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#21 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(81): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#22 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure), Object(Closure))
#23 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure), Array, NULL)
#24 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1158): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Object(Closure))
#25 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(182): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->terminate()
#26 /var/www/html/laravel/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response))
#27 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that `jkocik/laravel-profiler` made a request. Simply removing it from the packages resolved the problem.